# Trailing Ampersand character not shown in jquery tooltip (only in IE)

Tags: jquery, tooltip, jquery-tooltip

When I have the Jquery tooltip applied on a image element, defined as such:

```
<img id="c" title="abc &amp; ced &amp;" src="info.png" />
```

The actual tooltip that is shown is:

```
"abc & ced "
```

In firefox, and when I add a trailing space after the last `&amp`, it works as intended:

```
"abc & ced &"
```

Is this an IE bug? I seem to be having it in version 7, 8 and 9 of IE...

Edit; the Jquery tooltip used is the one from http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/

Comment: Which tooltip plugin are you using?

Comment: Have ammended the question to show which tooltip

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/scr4ve/HwSam/2/ works fine for me in IE8. What are you doing differently?

Comment: The above link works for me as well... I do have a later version of the tooltip (1.3)

Comment: Yep. Looks like a jQuery issue 1.3.2 works fine while 1.4.4 doesn't. http://jsfiddle.net/HwSam/11/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/HwSam/12/
Workaround: Add a space character at the end. :-/

Comment: Hmz, okay at least now I know. If you make a real answer of this, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crazy stuff. Weird IE bug somehow.

```
$("a")[0].innerHTML = "error & error &"
//IE removes "&" at the end
```

The tooltip plugin sets the innerHTML of his helper element. IE removes trailing "&"

1) [double-escape it](http://jsfiddle.net/HwSam/18/) (title looks wrong on non-JS browsers, works fine everywhere else)

2) Change [.html() to .text()](http://code.google.com/p/bassistance-plugins/source/browse/trunk/plugins/tooltip/jquery.tooltip.js?r=84#166) in the tooltip plugin. Titles including html code will fail.

3) Trailing space workaround

4) inspect further

Comment: Looks like IE innerHTML tries to render the last "&" and any characters that follows as an encoded entity and fails silently.  #3 is interesting, trailing space. Are they splitting words by space, and this bug is confined to the last word?  So, adding a space just adds an empty word. hahaha.